# Changing size of Notify Icon

Tags: c#, windows, notifyicon

As we know when we use notifyicon control in c# and place it in systemtray and it is displayed, windows overrides its size and make it 16*16 so can we somehow change its size? make it little bigger like system "date and time" display or like "input method type" in windows 8. I want to display certain text there.
Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system draws the icon, and it decides what size it is. For what it is worth, notification icons are the system's small icon size. So in fact you should not assume that they will be 16px icons. For font scalings larger than 100% the small icon size will be larger than 16px.

At the Win32 level, the application supplies an `HICON`, and the system draws that. If it needs to resize it, it will. You cannot custom draw in the notification area.

Imagine if applications could custom draw in the notification area? All it would take would be for a couple of applications to decide that they were so awesomely important that they had to custom draw large amounts of information. And then there'd be no room left for the rest of the taskbar.

So, the bottom line here is that you will need to find some other UI approach to solve your problem.